# group by one column, sum over another w. repeating entries (total transaction value for transactions incl a specific product)

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have a table of transactions, and would like to compute, for each product, the total transaction value of transactions including that product.

```
+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| TransactionId | ProductId | Quantity | UnitPrice |
+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|             1 | A         |        2 | 3.00      |
|             1 | B         |        1 | 6.00      |
|             2 | B         |        1 | 6.00      |
|             3 | A         |        6 | 3.00      |
|             3 | C         |        2 | 8.00      |
+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

For example, product A is in two transactions: transactions 1 and 3.  The total revenue from transaction 1 is 6.00 from product A and 6.00 from product B, total of 12.00.  The total revenue from transaction 3 is 18.00 from product A and 16.00 from product C, total of 34.00.  Therefore the total revenue from transactions including product A is 12.00 + 34.00 = 46.00.

I'd like to select the following (given the table above):

```
+-----------+----------------+
| ProductId | TotalBasketRev |
+-----------+----------------+
| A         | 46.00          |
| B         | 18.00          |
| C         | 34.00          |
+-----------+----------------+
```

I also need to be able to do this for Redshift.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: This result seems really useless to me... I guess you see which items are purchased by big spenders but I doubt that the actual results have much significant variance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need calculate total for each transaction.

Then join back to your original table and group by for each product to sum the total of each participating transaction.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c0c88/5)

```
SELECT T."ProductId", SUM(TTotal.total)
FROM Transactions T
JOIN
    (
      SELECT "TransactionId", SUM ("Quantity" * "UnitPrice") total
      FROM Transactions
      GROUP BY "TransactionId"
    ) Ttotal
  ON T."TransactionId" = TTotal."TransactionId"
GROUP BY  T."ProductId"    
ORDER BY  T."ProductId"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ProductId | sum |
|-----------|-----|
|         A |  46 |
|         B |  18 |
|         C |  34 |
```